# оператор || c++

Tags: c++

Есть инструкция:

```
if (выражение 1 || выражение 2) .
```

Если `выражение 1` истинно, то `выражение 2` не вычисляется. Как временно отключить это?

Comment: какая директива если есть????

Comment: написать if (выражение 1 | выражение 2)  тогда оба вычисляться

Comment: @Suvitruf: Это покатит если тип выражений — не число.

Comment: В том то и прикол что второе не вычисляе

Comment: Выражение типа if (a=b || c=d), когда первое тру второе не присваивает нехрена

Comment: Используйте java.

Comment: @zenden2k: А у Java `||` не short-circuiting? o_O

Comment: не просто там `|` является логическим оператором а не битовым

Comment: @VladD а в C++ даже в boolean можно засунуть что угодно и битовый оператор обломится

Comment: @zenden2k: Аааа! Ну да, в шарпе тоже (если на `bool`-выражениях).

Answer (score 11):

Никак. Откройте любой учебник и прочитайте, что оператор `||` работает так и никак иначе.

Если вы хотите управлять промежуточными вычислениями, используйте явные вспомогательные переменные:

```
bool b1 = выражение1;
bool b2 = выражение2;
if (b1 || b2) ...
```

Для случая, когда ваши выражения другого типа, применяйте `auto` вместо `bool` (или правильный тип).

Для случая `a = b || c = d`, упомянутого в комментариях, покатит просто

```
a = b;
c = d;
if (a || c) ...
```

(заодно и код получается читабельнее.)

Comment: как так то даже в настройках компилятора незя? (dev c++)

Comment: @KILLER228: Это стандарт языка. Оператор `||` работает так по определению.

Comment: ППЦ ну лан пасяб

Comment: @KILLER228: Намана! Пажалусто!

Comment: В некоторых языках можно. В Делфи, например, есть директива {$B+} переключающая между коротким и полным вычислением всех условий.

Comment: @KromStern: /me неодобряэ, это spooky action at a distance. Вы написали код, который рассчитывает на short circuiting, потом в проекте — бац! — кто-то ради одного хака переключил настройку, и у вас баг.

Comment: @KromStern: Хотя конечно это не отменяет того факта, что в Делфи такая фича и правда есть.

Comment: Естественно это ересь. В 9999 случаях из 10000. Кстати эта директива емнип, как и многие другие, может быть использована как обертка для некоторых строк, а не на весь проект целиком.

Comment: @KromStern: А вот если это можно обернуть локально, тогда это уже фича, а не баг. Не знал.

Answer (score 3):

Как обычно, под занавес еще 5 копеек (обратите внимание, никаких лишних операций)

```
if (a = b, c = d || b)
  puts("not 00");
```

(результатом операции `,` является результат `c = d`).

А временно (или на неопределенный промежуток) отменить правило вычисления `||` конечно же (о чем все уже сказали) не получится.

Comment: «никаких лишних операций» — ну... вы ведь наверняка не один раз смотрели в ассемблерный листинг и знаете намного лучше меня, что вспомогательные переменные будут элиминированы наверное даже на `-O1`.

Comment: @VladD,  проверял в gcc -O3 и все работает.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что код что с доп. переменными, что без них произведёт одинаковый ассемблерный листинг. Я ни на секунду не сомневался в правильности вашего кода (даже не читая его).

Comment: Признаться, я не понимаю, почему все зациклились на ||, когда довольно очевидным и логичным решением является использование &&.

Comment: @mikelsv очевидным является вынос вычисления обязательных выражений из условия, а не замена `||` на `&&` с последующим усложнением понимания кода.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно выбросить || и взять &&: if (!( выражение 1 && выражение 2)) тогда оба выражения будут вычисляться.

Comment: Подождите-подождите. Раньше: `if (0 || 1)` вычисляет и 0, и 1. Сейчас `if (!(0 && 1))` вычисляет только 0.

Comment: Кроме того, раньше `if (0 || 0)` даёт результат `if (0)`. А сейчас `if (!(0 && 0))` даёт результат `if (!0)`.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, тут ошибка. Я тоже понял, что написал неправильно, но мне стало интересно, кто плюсует ответ и до скольки это будет продолжаться.

Comment: Будем считать ваш ответ проверкой на внимательность :)

Comment: Я заплюсовал, а потом (уже через пару часов при сборке мебели) тоже понял, что это не работает. Вот, вернулся, а отыграть голос назад система не дает...

Answer (score 2):

Использовать "побитное или":

```
if ((a=b)!=0 | (c=d)!=0)
```

Comment: код стал гораздо понятнее :-P

Comment: не ето все гг вот я зрабил костыль
if (((a=b) && (c=d)) || (c=d))
то что надо сначала присваивает только первое и если тру то и второе а нет так идет и там присваивает и если уж в первом фолс то там уж точно будет тру в итоге все пашет

Comment: проверьте сами и ни надо некаких дополнительных переменных

Comment: зато терь функция в 4 строчки ёу

Comment: @KILLER228: За такую функцию в 4 строчки вас выгонят с работы. Это нечитаемый и неподдерживаемый в принципе код.

Comment: можно впринципе в 3 но тогда там ваще черт ногу сломит

Comment: нафига читабельность? главное память и скорость

Comment: если надо читабельность то там строчек 15 будет и весь мой код увеличится раз в 5 в чем смысл

Comment: @KILLER228: Вот в этот момент вас уже и уволили без выходного. Перед тем как устраиваться в следующую контору, откомпилируйте читаемый и нечитаемый вариант кода со включенной оптимизацией и курите ассемблерный выхлоп вплоть до просветления.

Comment: Не, главное свой код никому не показывать, тогда не выгонят :)

Comment: блин баги полезли черт

Comment: @KILLER228: Я ж говорил, что код неподдерживаемый. Вот вас эта неподдерживаемость и клюнула тут же.

Comment: ниче 3 часа писал еще попишу

Answer (score 2):

"Временно отключить" правило вычисления оператора || нельзя. Но если выражения имеют определенные пользователем типы, то вы можете перегрузить оператор || для этих типов. В этом случае оба выражения в левой и правой части от знака оператора будут вычисляться.

С другой стороны, вы можете просто заменить использование данного оператора на эквивалентное выражение, которое даст вам точно такой же результат.

Попробуйте сделать следующим образом:

```
if ( !!выражение1 + !!выражение2 ) { /*...*/ }
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

bool expression1() 
{ 
    std::cout << "expression1" << std::endl;
    return true;
}    

bool expression2() 
{ 
    std::cout << "expression2" << std::endl;
    return false;
}    

int main()
{

    if ( !!expression1() + !!expression2() ) std::cout << "It seems it works!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
expression1
expression2
It seems it works!
```

Или можете записать вместо выражения

```
if ( !!expression1() + !!expression2() )
```

следующее выражение

```
if ( bool( expression1() ) + bool( expression2() ) )
```

То есть это общий подход, когда необязательно, что выражение1 и выражение2 имеют булевы значения. В общем случае они могут иметь даже разные типы. Например, одно выражение может иметь тип `double`, а другое выражение тип `char *`.

В частном случае, когда оба выражения имеют булевы значения `true` или `false`, то вы можете написать просто

```
if ( expression1() + expression2() )
```

Comment: у вас 2 ! вместо 1

Comment: @KILLER228: `if (2)` равносильно `if (1)`.

Comment: я про !! вместо !

Comment: @KILLER228 Все правильно. Это чтобы любое выражение привести к булевскому значению.:)

Comment: в том то и прикол что бул не надо писать так как = возвращает свое значение которое при 0 у меня в фолсе

Comment: if (0) if (3) или if (bool(0)) if (bool(3)) яка розница

Comment: @KILLER228 Ничего не понял. Любое выражение в if предложении преобразуется к булевому значению.

Comment: ну дык так зачем там бул

Comment: @KILLER228: Но почему-то ваш код не работает, а код из этого ответа работает. :) Парадокс?

Comment: у вас компьютер сломался значит

Comment: @KILLER228 Я не понимаю, что у вас вызывает вопросы.

Comment: ай я пошел !!!!!!!4

Comment: @KILLER228 Это полный эквивалент того, что вам необходимо.

Comment: @KILLER228 Я продемонстрировал общий подход, когда выражения могут иметь, например, арифметическое значение. Если ваши выражения возвращают булевы выражения, то конечно можете не делать приведение результатов выражений к булеву типу.

Comment: всё терь работает переписал на 5 строчек :(

Comment: @KILLER228 Не знаю, что вы там переписывали на 5 строчек. Я вам показал, как это можно сделать в одну строчку.